# Delete rows of a datatable from another datatable & Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Along with saying hello,
I need to delete rows from a datatable, but only the rows that are contained in another datatable, I have tried with Linq, but I can't find a way to do it without a loop (ForEach), someone has been able to achieve it for me guide. Very thankful.

```
    Dim dtTemporal As DataTable 
    

    dtTemporal = objTable.Copy
    dtTemporal.AcceptChanges()

   'Avoid this, for performance, use Linq
    For Each _row As DataRow In dtTemporal.Rows
       objTable.Rows.Remove(_row)
   Next
```

Comment: "Avoid this, for performance, use Linq" Why do you assume, LINQ would be any faster? In fact it just is syntactic sugar that adds absolutely no additional logic that would improve your performance. Furthermore the Q within LINQ stands for **querying**, not **modifying**. Thus you can´t delete rows with LINQ.

Comment: I understand, Linq is not to delete, but I am looking for a way to make it simpler and avoid falling into a loop. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Linq uses loops internally. You are not avoiding a loop.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you're database is.  If it's SQL based, then perhaps consider deleting that data directly from the DB via SQL delete commands/stored procedures

Comment: Is this using LINQ to Datasets? That isn't going to help you on delete operations.

Comment: LINQ **is** `foreach` under the hood. It´s only hidden to the user. You gain absoluteley **nothing** by replacing a simple loop by a LINQ-statement.